# Apache (xampp) doesn't run on Win 10 - W3SVC not running

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I've read the other questions about Apache not running on Windows 10, but I've checked my list of running services, and there isn't any W3SVC, World Wide Web Publishing Services, or Skype running automatically.

I also tried editing the config files to change the port to 81 or 122, but that didn't work.

I opened cmd and ran netstat -a to check ports, but I don't know how to read this information to tell which is port 80 and what service is using it.

I upgraded the computer from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Wamp, and it worked right away, without any errors or problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, xampp shouldn't have any issue running on windows 10.

To get to know the actual error, try to start apache. Due to error, apache won't start but it also adds logs to window's event viewer as well as apache log file.

To access windows log(image 1 and 2) and apache log(image 3)

1. check event viewer log as shown into attached image. (image1)
2. go to application log and check log with red exclamation sign. (image2)
3. Also to make sure apache's own log by going to apache installation  directory 
   and open error log as shown into attached image.[image: Windows and apache error log] (image3).

Comment: Hi there,
Neither the Event Viewer or Apache error logs are showing events related to my trying to turn on Apache this morning.  Apache error log has some errors from two months ago.  Event Viewer has an application error for Skypehost.exe with the timestamp of when I turned on my computer this morning.